# Azure application insights disable favicon check

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a regular mvc app. How can I disable app insights from checking for favicon.ico?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom [TelemetryFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor) that prevents telemetry from being send to application insights:

```cs
public class CustomTelemetryFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private readonly ITelemetryProcessor _next;

    public CustomTelemetryFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        // Example: process all telemetry except requests to favicon
        var isFavIconUrl = item is RequestTelemetry request && request.Url.ToString().EndsWith("favicon.ico");

        if (!isFavIconUrl)
            _next.Process(item); // Process the item only if it is not the request for favicon
    }
}
```

The last step is to register your filter, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor) on how to do that for your specific runtime.